# how to perform tokenization and stopword removal in C#?

Tags: c#, tokenize, stop-words

Basically i want to tokenise each word of the paragraph and then perform stopword removal. Which will be preprocessed data for my algorithm.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all punctuation and split the string for whitespace.

```
string s = "This is, a sentence.";
s = s.Replace(",","").Replace(".");
string words[] = s.split(" ");
```

Comment: Your right about spilt(" "), but i need to keep the punctuation's.

Comment: If you need them... just don't remove them :)

Comment: +1. This is probably as good as it could get for the question asked. The topic itself is complex enough (unless it is homework) since not all languages use space as separators... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing gives some proper terms/concepts to start searching for.

Answer (score 0):

if read from text file or any text you can:

```
  char[] dele = { ' ', ',', '.', '\t', ';', '#', '!' };
  List<string> allLinesText = File.ReadAllText(text file).Split(dele).ToList();
```

then you can convert stop-words to dictionary and save your document to list then

```
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> word in StopWords)
       {
          if (list.contain(word.key))
               list.RemovAll(s=>s==word.key);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all separation symbols and stopwords in constants or db:

```
   public static readonly char[] WordsSeparators = {
        ' ', '\t', '\n', '\n', '\r', '\u0085'
    };

  public static readonly string[] StopWords = {
        "stop", "word", "is", "here"
    };
```

Remove all puctuations. Split text and filter:

```
var words = new List<string>();
var stopWords = new HashSet<string>(TextOperationConstants.StopWords);
foreach (var term in text.Split(TextOperationConstants.WordsSeparators))
{
      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term)) continue;
      if (stopWords.Contains(term)) continue;
      words .Add(term);
}
```